# Gradle Sync failed for Android Studio 1.1.0

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I'm running Android Studio 1.1.0 for a class but I cannot get the emulator to load properly. I'm getting the error, Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+. I've already tried installing the repository and syncing the project again.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to the current version of [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio), which is `3.5.2`. This also provides you with an updated Gradle plugin (version `1.1.0` might not know about repository `google()` yet - which could only be setup as regular `maven` repository with such an old version of the IDE).